# setting the target equal to 17 and using the openConnection() method

Tags: android

When I read android document, I see that many packages about `HTTP` are deprecated and it is better if we use   the `openConnection()` method.

> This class was deprecated **in API level 22**. Please use openConnection()
>   instead. Please visit this webpage for further details.

If I set `minSdkVersion="8"` and `targetSdkVersion="17"`, can I use the `openConnection()` method on the version of 2.2 and the higher versions?

Comment: You can use `openConnection()` in any API version, it was added in API level 1.